# Why does GDB backtrace comes up with ?? () when remote debugging with vgdb?

Tags: c++, gdb, valgrind

I'm running valgrind with `valgrind --vgdb-error=0 <binary> <binary args>` in one shell and `gdb <binary>` in another. I connect to the `valgrind` server from `gdb` with `target remote | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=<pid>`. I `continue` on `gdb` and receive a `SIGTRAP` and check the backtrace:

```
Remote debugging using | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=<pid>
relaying data between gdb and process <pid>
warning: remote target does not support file transfer, attempting to access files from local filesystem.
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/ld-2.26.so.debug...done.
done.
0x0000000004000ef0 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) c
Continuing.
warning: Probes-based dynamic linker interface failed.
Reverting to original interface.

[New Thread 15252]
[New Thread 15249]
[New Thread 15250]
[New Thread 15253]
[New Thread 15254]

Thread 2 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
[Switching to Thread 15252]
0x0000000004c2eb99 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000004c2eb99 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000008b6ae50 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000042a980 in std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, retracted_type> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_assign<std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, retracted_type> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::operator=(std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, retracted_type> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&)::{lambda(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, false> const*)#1}>(std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, retracted_type> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&, std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, retracted_type> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::operator=(std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, retracted_type> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&)::{lambda(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<long const, retracted_type>, false> const*)#1} const&) (this=0x4f6fc02, __ht=..., __node_gen=...) at /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:1139
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

I ran `file` on the binary

```
$ file <binary name>
<binary name>: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, not stripped
```

Why does the GDB backtrace come up with `?? ()` in the backtrace?

Additionally the backtrace seems shorter than it should be. Is that because `the frame did not save the PC`? Why/how did the program counter not get saved?

Is there anyway I can get more information to help debug? Normal `gdb` debugging normally resolves symbols for the backtrace.

**EDIT:**
Adding additional output that was requested in the comments

```
(gdb) info shared
From                To                  Syms Read   Shared Object Library
0x0000000004000d70  0x000000000401c570  Yes         /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) info file
Symbols from "/home/ec2-user/<redacted>".
Remote serial target in gdb-specific protocol:
Debugging a target over a serial line.
        While running this, GDB does not access memory from...
Local exec file:
        `/home/ec2-user/<redacted>', file type elf64-x86-64.
        Entry point: 0x40f000
        0x0000000000400270 - 0x000000000040028c is .interp
        0x000000000040028c - 0x00000000004002ac is .note.ABI-tag
        0x00000000004002b0 - 0x000000000040135c is .hash
        0x0000000000401360 - 0x0000000000404660 is .dynsym
        0x0000000000404660 - 0x00000000004088e7 is .dynstr
        0x00000000004088e8 - 0x0000000000408d28 is .gnu.version
        0x0000000000408d28 - 0x0000000000408fd8 is .gnu.version_r
        0x0000000000408fd8 - 0x0000000000409530 is .rela.dyn
        0x0000000000409530 - 0x000000000040c4a0 is .rela.plt
        0x000000000040c4a0 - 0x000000000040c4bc is .init
        0x000000000040c4c0 - 0x000000000040e470 is .plt
        0x000000000040f000 - 0x0000000000ac8890 is .text
        0x0000000000ac8890 - 0x0000000000ac8899 is .fini
        0x0000000000ac88c0 - 0x0000000000e67008 is .rodata
        0x0000000000e67008 - 0x0000000000eb44dc is .eh_frame_hdr
        0x0000000000eb44e0 - 0x0000000000ff1fb0 is .eh_frame
        0x0000000000ff1fb0 - 0x0000000001006236 is .gcc_except_table
        0x0000000001206db0 - 0x0000000001206dd0 is .tbss
        0x0000000001206db0 - 0x0000000001206f78 is .init_array
        0x0000000001206f78 - 0x0000000001206f80 is .fini_array
        0x0000000001206f80 - 0x0000000001243c70 is .data.rel.ro
        0x0000000001243c70 - 0x0000000001243ec0 is .dynamic
        0x0000000001243ec0 - 0x0000000001243ff8 is .got
        0x0000000001244000 - 0x0000000001244fe8 is .got.plt
        0x0000000001245000 - 0x000000000156db88 is .data
        0x000000000156dba0 - 0x000000000157d9b0 is .bss
        0x00000000040001c8 - 0x00000000040001ec is .note.gnu.build-id in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x00000000040001f0 - 0x00000000040002b4 is .hash in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x00000000040002b8 - 0x00000000040003a0 is .gnu.hash in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x00000000040003a0 - 0x0000000004000670 is .dynsym in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004000670 - 0x000000000400083c is .dynstr in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x000000000400083c - 0x0000000004000878 is .gnu.version in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004000878 - 0x000000000400091c is .gnu.version_d in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004000920 - 0x0000000004000c68 is .rela.dyn in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004000c68 - 0x0000000004000cf8 is .rela.plt in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004000d00 - 0x0000000004000d70 is .plt in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004000d70 - 0x000000000401c570 is .text in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x000000000401c580 - 0x0000000004020980 is .rodata in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004020980 - 0x0000000004020981 is .stapsdt.base in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004020984 - 0x0000000004021008 is .eh_frame_hdr in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004021008 - 0x000000000402346c is .eh_frame in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004223780 - 0x0000000004223e14 is .data.rel.ro in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004223e18 - 0x0000000004223fa8 is .dynamic in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004223fa8 - 0x0000000004224000 is .got in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004224000 - 0x0000000004224f78 is .data in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
        0x0000000004224f80 - 0x0000000004225130 is .bss in /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

Valgrind Output:

```
==2693== Thread 4:
==2693== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==2693==    at 0x4C2EB99: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==2693==    by 0x42A97F: <redacted_func_1>() (in /home/ec2-user/bin/<redacted>)
==2693==    by 0x4353BD: <redacted_func_2>() (in /home/ec2-user/bin/<redacted>)
==2693==    by 0x4F05F6F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:80)
==2693==    by 0x562140A: start_thread (pthread_create.c:465)
==2693==    by 0x5E7CE7E: clone (clone.S:95)
==2693==
==2693== (action on error) vgdb me ...
```

Valgrind Version

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-111 ~]$ valgrind --version
valgrind-3.13.0
```

GDB Version

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-111 ~]$ gdb --version
GNU gdb (GDB) Red Hat Enterprise Linux 8.0.1-30.amzn2.0.3
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
```

GLIBC Version

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-111 ~]$ ldd --version
ldd (GNU libc) 2.26
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
Written by Roland McGrath and Ulrich Drepper.
```

**EDIT 2:**
Following @Employed Russian instructions:

Find the address of the `.text` section of the binary

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-111 ~]$ readelf -WS ~/<redacted> | grep '\.text'
  [12] .text             PROGBITS        000000000040f000 00f000 6b9890 00  AX  0   0 4096
```

Spun up `valgrind` and `gdb` in the same manner as described earlier and manually added the symbol file:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file <redacted> 0x000000000040f000
add symbol table from file "<redacted>" at
        .text_addr = 0x40f000
```

Valgrind Output:

```
==5915== Thread 4:
==5915== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==5915==    at 0x4C2EB99: strlen (vg_replace_strmem.c:458)
==5915==    by 0x42A97F: <redacted function 1>() (in /home/ec2-user/bin/<redacted>)
==5915==    by 0x4353BD: <redacted function 2>() (in /home/ec2-user/bin/<redacted>)
==5915==    by 0x4F05F6F: execute_native_thread_routine (thread.cc:80)
==5915==    by 0x562140A: start_thread (pthread_create.c:465)
==5915==    by 0x5E7CE7E: clone (clone.S:95)
==5915==
==5915== (action on error) vgdb me ...
```

GDB Output:

```
(gdb)  target remote | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5915
Remote debugging using | /usr/lib64/valgrind/../../bin/vgdb --pid=5915
relaying data between gdb and process 5915
warning: remote target does not support file transfer, attempting to access files from local filesystem.
Reading symbols from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/usr/lib64/ld-2.26.so.debug...done.
done.
0x0000000004000ef0 in _start () from /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
(gdb) c
Continuing.
warning: Probes-based dynamic linker interface failed.
Reverting to original interface.

[New Thread 6502]
[New Thread 6492]
[New Thread 6498]
[New Thread 6503]
[New Thread 6504]

Thread 2 received signal SIGTRAP, Trace/breakpoint trap.
[Switching to Thread 6502]
0x0000000004c2eb99 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x0000000004c2eb99 in ?? ()
#1  0x0000000008b6ae50 in ?? ()
#2  0x000000000042a980 in std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::_M_assign<std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::operator=(std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&)::{lambda(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, false> const*)#1}>(std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&, std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> >::operator=(std::_Hashtable<long, std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, std::allocator<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>> >, std::__detail::_Select1st, std::equal_to<long>, std::hash<long>, std::__detail::_Mod_range_hashing, std::__detail::_Default_ranged_hash, std::__detail::_Prime_rehash_policy, std::__detail::_Hashtable_traits<false, false, true> > const&)::{lambda(std::__detail::_Hash_node<std::pair<long const, <redacted function>>, false> const*)#1} const&) (this=0x4f6fc02, __ht=..., __node_gen=...) at /usr/local/include/c++/9.2.0/bits/hashtable.h:1149
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
```

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-12-111 ~]$ cat /proc/5915/maps
00400000-00c1f000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 922996444                         /home/ec2-user/bin/<redacted>
00e1e000-00e5c000 r--p 0081e000 103:01 922996444                         /home/ec2-user/bin/<redacted>
00e5c000-01167000 rw-p 0085c000 103:01 922996444                         /home/ec2-user/bin/<redacted>
01167000-01172000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
04000000-04024000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1372                              /usr/lib64/ld-2.26.so
04024000-04028000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
04031000-04036000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
04223000-04224000 r--p 00023000 103:01 1372                              /usr/lib64/ld-2.26.so
04224000-04225000 rw-p 00024000 103:01 1372                              /usr/lib64/ld-2.26.so
04225000-04226000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
04226000-04227000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
04a26000-04a27000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 291504350                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04a27000-04c26000 ---p 00001000 103:01 291504350                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04c26000-04c27000 r--p 00000000 103:01 291504350                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04c27000-04c28000 rw-p 00001000 103:01 291504350                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04c28000-04c37000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 291504362                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04c37000-04e36000 ---p 0000f000 103:01 291504362                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04e36000-04e37000 r--p 0000e000 103:01 291504362                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04e37000-04e38000 rw-p 0000f000 103:01 291504362                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04e38000-04ffe000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 4676257                           /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
04ffe000-051fd000 ---p 001c6000 103:01 4676257                           /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
051fd000-05208000 r--p 001c5000 103:01 4676257                           /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
05208000-0520b000 rw-p 001d0000 103:01 4676257                           /usr/local/lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.27
0520b000-0520e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
0520e000-05215000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1402                              /usr/lib64/librt-2.26.so
05215000-05414000 ---p 00007000 103:01 1402                              /usr/lib64/librt-2.26.so
05414000-05415000 r--p 00006000 103:01 1402                              /usr/lib64/librt-2.26.so
05415000-05416000 rw-p 00007000 103:01 1402                              /usr/lib64/librt-2.26.so
05416000-05419000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1384                              /usr/lib64/libdl-2.26.so
05419000-05618000 ---p 00003000 103:01 1384                              /usr/lib64/libdl-2.26.so
05618000-05619000 r--p 00002000 103:01 1384                              /usr/lib64/libdl-2.26.so
05619000-0561a000 rw-p 00003000 103:01 1384                              /usr/lib64/libdl-2.26.so
0561a000-05632000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1398                              /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.26.so
05632000-05832000 ---p 00018000 103:01 1398                              /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.26.so
05832000-05833000 r--p 00018000 103:01 1398                              /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.26.so
05833000-05834000 rw-p 00019000 103:01 1398                              /usr/lib64/libpthread-2.26.so
05834000-05838000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
05838000-05977000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1386                              /usr/lib64/libm-2.26.so
05977000-05b76000 ---p 0013f000 103:01 1386                              /usr/lib64/libm-2.26.so
05b76000-05b77000 r--p 0013e000 103:01 1386                              /usr/lib64/libm-2.26.so
05b77000-05b78000 rw-p 0013f000 103:01 1386                              /usr/lib64/libm-2.26.so
05b78000-05b8e000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 4675484                           /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
05b8e000-05d8e000 ---p 00016000 103:01 4675484                           /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
05d8e000-05d8f000 r--p 00016000 103:01 4675484                           /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
05d8f000-05d90000 rw-p 00017000 103:01 4675484                           /usr/local/lib64/libgcc_s.so.1
05d90000-05f31000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1380                              /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so
05f31000-06131000 ---p 001a1000 103:01 1380                              /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so
06131000-06135000 r--p 001a1000 103:01 1380                              /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so
06135000-06137000 rw-p 001a5000 103:01 1380                              /usr/lib64/libc-2.26.so
06137000-0613b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
0613b000-0653b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
0653b000-0653c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
0653c000-06d3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
06d3c000-06d3d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
06d3d000-0753d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
0753d000-0793d000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
0793d000-07948000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1396                              /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.26.so
07948000-07b47000 ---p 0000b000 103:01 1396                              /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.26.so
07b47000-07b48000 r--p 0000a000 103:01 1396                              /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.26.so
07b48000-07b49000 rw-p 0000b000 103:01 1396                              /usr/lib64/libnss_files-2.26.so
07b49000-07b4f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
07b4f000-07b54000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1394                              /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.26.so
07b54000-07d53000 ---p 00005000 103:01 1394                              /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.26.so
07d53000-07d54000 r--p 00004000 103:01 1394                              /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.26.so
07d54000-07d55000 rw-p 00005000 103:01 1394                              /usr/lib64/libnss_dns-2.26.so
07d55000-07d67000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 1400                              /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.26.so
07d67000-07f67000 ---p 00012000 103:01 1400                              /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.26.so
07f67000-07f68000 r--p 00012000 103:01 1400                              /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.26.so
07f68000-07f69000 rw-p 00013000 103:01 1400                              /usr/lib64/libresolv-2.26.so
07f69000-07f6b000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
07f6b000-0836b000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
0836b000-0836c000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
0836c000-08b6c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
08b6c000-08b6d000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
08b6d000-0936d000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
0936d000-0936e000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
0936e000-09b6e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
58000000-5823c000 r-xp 00000000 103:01 291504283                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
5843c000-5843f000 rw-p 0023c000 103:01 291504283                         /usr/lib64/valgrind/memcheck-amd64-linux
5843f000-59e41000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
1002001000-1002f04000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1002f06000-1002f8a000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1002f8c000-1002fb0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1002fb0000-1002fb2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
1002fb2000-10030b2000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
10030b2000-10030b4000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
10030b4000-10030b5000 rw-s 00000000 103:01 218555                        /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5915-by-ec2-user-on-ip-172-31-12-111.ap-northeast-1.compute.internal
10030b5000-10058d7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
10058d7000-10058d9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
10058d9000-10059d9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
10059d9000-10059db000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
10059db000-1005af3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1005af6000-1005cde000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1005cde000-1005ce0000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
1005ce0000-1005de0000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1005de0000-1005de2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
1005de2000-1005dea000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1005deb000-1006c9f000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1006c9f000-1006ca1000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
1006ca1000-1006da1000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1006da1000-1006da3000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
1006da3000-1006fa3000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1006fa3000-1006fa5000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
1006fa5000-10070a5000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
10070a5000-10070a7000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
10070a7000-10072a7000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
10072a7000-10072a9000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
10072a9000-10073a9000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
10073a9000-10073ab000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
10073ab000-10073eb000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0
1ffeffa000-1fff001000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
7ffed08e8000-7ffed0909000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
7ffed0964000-7ffed0967000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                          [vvar]
ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]
```

Comment: Your binary is compiled with debug info? Do you use -fomit-frame-pointer?

Comment: I outputted the `file` output which indicates the binary was not stripped. Additionally `objdump --syms <binary name>` also has symbols output

Comment: What is the output from `(gdb) info shared` and `info file`? What is the output from `valgrind` (in the other window)?

Comment: @EmployedRussian added requested output

Comment: The issue is pretty clear from the output you added, but to reproduce (and possibly find a solution) I would need to know the versions of GLIBC, GDB, and Valgrind you are using.

Comment: @EmployedRussian added requested version information. I'm a bit lost as to what the issue is, do you mind explaining?

Comment: You can ask valgrind to output its mapping by doing from gdb: monitor v.info memory aspacemgr   This will output the list of files, and the mapped segments.  You can relate a mapped segment with its name using the (x,y) at the end of the segment that is the same as the first (x,y,z) in front of the mapped file name.

Comment: I didn't ask what the output of `file` is. And I didn't ask what the output of `objdump` is. Let's try again. _Is your binary compiled with debug info?_. And _do you use -fomit-frame-pointer?_

Comment: The reason why I gave the output of `file` and indicated that `objdump --syms` has symbols output is to show that the binary was compiled with debug info. I am not use `-fomit-frame-pointer` either.

Answer (score 1):

The *cause* of "bad stack" is pretty clear from the `info file` output: GDB *thinks* that `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2` is loaded at `0x4000000`, but we know that it's the main binary that is loaded at that address, and `ld-linux` is loaded elsewhere.

You can confirm this by examining `/proc/$pid/maps`.

Why would GDB think that `ld-linux` is at `0x4000000`? Because *something* didn't quite work. GDB did say:

```
warning: Probes-based dynamic linker interface failed.
Reverting to original interface.
```

but apparently the "reverting" part didn't work either.

You *may* be able to work around this by manually adding symbols from the main binary to GDB:

```
(gdb) add-symbol-file /home/ec2-user/<redacted> $addr
```

where `$addr` is the address of `.text` section in main executable (use `readelf -WS /home/ec2-user/<redacted> | grep '\.text'` to find that address).

Comment: I've edited my post to show the steps I used while following your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem like the workaround worked

Comment: @ajoseps You need to use `add-symbol-file` _after_ GDB stops with `SIGTRAP`, not before. It's unclear whether you did or not.

Comment: i tried it with before and after the `SIGTRAP` with the same result

Comment: @ajoseps I was unable to replicate the behavior you observed using GLIBC-2.31 and 2.27, valgrind-3.17 and GDB-10.0. I _suspect_ that something is wrong with your GLIBC build, but don't really know what it could be. What is the provenance of that GLIBC?

Comment: it’s the one provided by AWS ec2 Amazon Linux. I was able to compile the same binary on my local laptop with full symbols, so I’m incline to believe it’s an issue with the tool chain I compiled with